# Entity FrameWork и наследование

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

Прошу разрешить диллему, суть которой такова:
Есть БД с сущностями представляющими факультет (студент, преподаватель, оценки, кафедры, и т.д.), сделанная с помощью EF CodeFirst.
Есть WinForms приложение с кнопочками и прочим. (не суть)
Преподаватель поставил задачу: создать разные учетные записи, присвоить им роли и в зависимости от роли - разный функционал. Я решил таким путем : просто 3 разные формы показываются в зависимости от роли: админ - одна форма, студент - другая, преподаватель - третья. Вопрос же в том, как мне связать LoginModel, в которой содержатся Login, Password и сущности студента или преподавателя.

Грубо говоря: вводим данные в форму для входа, просматриваем в БД совпадения и нашли того пользователя User, у него есть Role. Тут разобрались. Но представим, что учетная запись User связана с студентом и он может просматривать свои данные, тогда нам надо User связать с Student один к одному. Но а если это преподаватель? Значит надо связать и с преподавателем один к одному - костыль, т.к. при добавлении других сущностей у нас будут добавляться связи, из которых только одна будет не null.

Comment: 3 роли, студент, препод и админ?

Comment: Да, роли 3. Так же есть класс User, Role (связаны 1-n) и два класса Student, Professor.
Так вот. какая должна быть связь между user и student, professor. Чтоб если мы зайдем под user с ролью студента с ролью студента он увидит только свои данные, а если зайдем под User с ролью профессор то он увидит только свои предметы

Comment: зачем вам классы Student и Professor? Сделайте класс User и смотрите его роли. Если у юзера роль админа - показывайте админку, если профессора - то окно для профессора, если студент - окно для студента. Ну и что мешает профессору быть ещё и админом?

Comment: это классы бизнес-логики, у каждого их них еще есть привязка к ведомостям, оценкам, (для студентов), к преподаваемым предметам и кафедрам (для профессоров)

Comment: Ваши классы бизнес логики не должны иметь никакого отношения к схеме БД и к EntiyFramework. Их вы можете создавать любым для вас подходяшим способом

Comment: не пойму, как это классы, которые в EF Framework переходят в таблицы не должны быть связаны с EF Framework. Типичная анемичная модель

Comment: Вы искажаете смысл того, что я вам написал. Прочитайте внимательней. Я сказал, что классы уровня доступа к данным не являются классами вашей бизнес логики.

Comment: Если так, нет идей, как мне привязать юзера к студенту либо преподавателю ?
Провайдеры аутентификации лучше не предлагать, слишком сложно для winform.

Comment: Я в принципе не очень понимаю, зачем вам классы студента и преподвателя, и что вы будете делать, если какой то студент начнет преподавать или станет админом. Но привязка юзера к вашим классам зависит от вашех классов и ни как не связана с аутентификацией или базами данных. А вы ваши классы не показали в вашем вопросе, потому что то вам подсказать по коду, что видели только вы, я не могу.

Comment: В классе студента, считаем, находятся его личные данные (ФИО) и связанные данные (группа, оценки и проч)...то же самое и у Преподавателя, это классы бизнес логики. Отдельный студент может зайти в приложение под своей учеткой, связанной с сущностью его Студента, тогда на форму вываливаются только его данные.
Для преподавателя то же самое.
Все меняется когда под учеткой входит админ, у которого есть списки и студентов и преподов и доступны все операции CRUD, в отличии от студента и преподавателя. Стало понятнее ?

Comment: Все также не понятно, что будет, когда студент станет админом - будет он 2 итерфейса видеть? Или ему придется выбирать, как заходить? В любом случае, то, что вы описываете - это детали бизнес логики, они никак не связаны с хранением данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробую привести пример, чтобы было понятно о чем я.

Допустим, у нас есть следующая бизнес логика.

```
#region Business logic 

public abstract class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public abstract void SayHello();
}


public class Student : Person
{
    public override void SayHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello, Im {this.Name} and Im a Student");
    }
}

public class Admin : Person
{
    public override void SayHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello, Im {this.Name} and Im a Admin");
    }
}

public class Professor : Person
{
    public override void SayHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello, Im {this.Name} and Im a Professor");
    }
}

#endregion
```

Давайте напишем часть слоя для хранения данных для неё.

```
#region database

public class Repository
{
    public Person GetUser (string name){
        var context = new DatabaseContext();
        var dto = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
        if (dto.Roles.Contains("Admin")) return new Admin() {Name = dto.Name};
        if (dto.Roles.Contains("Student")) return new Student() {Name = dto.Name};
        if (dto.Roles.Contains("Professor")) return new Professor() {Name = dto.Name};
        return null;
    }
}

public class DatabaseContext 
{
    public List<UserDto> Users { get; set; } = 
        new List<UserDto>() {
            new UserDto() {
                Name = "Vasya",
                Roles = new List<string>(){"Student"}
            },
            new UserDto() {
                Name = "Petya",
                Roles = new List<string>(){"Professor"}
            },
            new UserDto() {
                Name = "Kolya",
                Roles = new List<string>(){"Admin"}
            }
            };
}


public class UserDto{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public List<string> Roles {get;set;} = new List<string>();
}

#endregion
```

Как видите, храним мы только юзеров и роли. Нам не надо хранить студентов или ещё что то.

Проверим наше предположение

```
var repo = new Repository();
var user = repo.GetUser("Vasya");
user.SayHello();
```

Вывод получится

```
Hello, Im Vasya and Im a Student
```

Отмечу также, что во  многих случаях отдельные классы бизнес логики для ролей типа Студент или Профессор вообще не нужны, и обычно возможности юзера зависят только от его ролей, потому необходимость отдельных классов остается на вашей совести.

Answer (score 3):

нужна таблица роли (админ, студент, препод, при необходимости можно добавить и другие роли), а у каждого User нужно указать не саму роль, а Id_роли (из таблицы ролей).

можно обойтись одной формой, просто в зависимости от роли отображаются либо не отображаются некоторые элементы формы

Comment: Да, про роли понятно, это и так есть. теперь, как связать User модель с моделями Professor и Student для того чтоб в зависимости от Creedential usera подтягивались определенная роль и определенные данные для студента или профессора

Comment: как и tym32167, считаю, что Вам не нужны отдельные модели Professor и Student) Просто делаете User с ролями и все

Comment: это классы бизнес-логики, у каждого их них еще есть привязка к ведомостям, оценкам, (для студентов), к преподаваемым предметам и кафедрам (для профессоров)

Comment: по части БД - в таблицах, содержащих информацию о составе групп, ведомостях, оценках (для студентов), преподаваемых предметах и кафедрах (для профессоров) вносятся Id_User

Comment: Так, значит ли это, что необходимость отпадает в таблицах Студент и Профессои о оставить толкьо User